# Sed manipulating lines of crontab

Tags: sed, cron

I would like use `sed` to delete a line from my crontab file.  First, I save the user's crontab in the file `text.txt`.  Then I would like to delete this line:

```
*/5 * * * * svn update /root/tamainut/schedule/generico.sh && sh /root/tamainut/schedule/generico.sh
```

I think the problem is with characters, but I'm lost.  I tried:

```
sed '*/5 * * * * svn update \/root\/tamainut\/schedule\/generico.sh && sh \/root\/tamainut\/schedule\/generico.sh/d' text.txt
sed: -e expresión #1, carácter 1: unknown command: `*'
```

I tried:

```
sed '\*/5 \* \* \* \* svn update \/root\/tamainut\/schedule\/generico.sh && sh \/root\/tamainut\/schedule\/generico.sh/d' text.txt 
sed: -e expresión #1, carácter 115: unterminated address regex
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 3):

`*` mean "*repeated any times*" in `sed` => use `\`:

```
sed '/\*\/5 \* \* \* \* svn update \/root\/tamainut\/schedule\/generico.sh && sh \/root\/tamainut\/schedule\/generico.sh/d' text.txt
```

You can also replace all `*` and `/` by `.` (this is less reliable, but more confortable to write: it is what I often do):

```
sed '/..5 . . . . svn update .root.tamainut.schedule.generico.sh && sh .root.tamainut.schedule.generico.sh/d' text.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
sed '/\*\/5 \* \* \* \* svn update \/root\/tamainut\/schedule\/generico.sh && sh \/root\/tamainut\/schedule\/generico.sh/d' text.txt
```

But I'd pick on one keyword, or a couple of keywords, that make the line unique and use them:

```
sed '/generico.sh.*generico.sh/d' text.txt
```

Your original ran into problems with no opening `/` to start the regex, and the `*` characters are metacharacters so they must be escaped too.

Answer (score 1):

If you can limit the search string, it will clean up the sed code.  If you must match the entire line, use a different delimiter on the address range:

```
$ sed '\|^\*/5 \* \* \* \* svn update /root/tamainut/schedule/generico.sh && sh /root/xxxx/file.sh$|d'
```

This allows you to avoid escaping the '/' characters.